# Perform an action after screen is scrolled

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm trying to show a toast after the screen is scrolled horizontally. The scrolling can happen anywhere on the screen, but I want the toast to appear only if the screen is scrolled from right to left. I have tried this:

```
HorizontalScrollView headerScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

       headerScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               Toast.makeText(Verbs.this, "The screen has been scrolled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return true;
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override setOnScrollChangeListener method to detect scrolling right to left.

```
HorizontalScrollView headerScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    headerScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollX > oldScrollX) {
                Toast.makeText(Verbs.this, "moved right to left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a scrollListener

```
HorizontalScrollView headerScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
headerScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); // For ScrollView
            int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX(); // For HorizontalScrollView
            // DO SOMETHING WITH THE SCROLL COORDINATES
        }
    });
```